# Is the configuration in startup.s file generated using KEIL IDE directly putting the Fcpu @ 60 MHz?

Tags: cpu, arm7

I am using LPC2148 for learning purpose and I was trying to mess around a lil bit with the startup.s file and understand it. In the Keil's Target option for the project it is assuming the XTAL frequency to be 12Mhz. I have this section of code

```
; Phase Locked Loop (PLL) definitions
PLL_BASE        EQU     0xE01FC080      ; PLL Base Address
PLLCON_OFS      EQU     0x00            ; PLL Control Offset
PLLCFG_OFS      EQU     0x04            ; PLL Configuration Offset
PLLSTAT_OFS     EQU     0x08            ; PLL Status Offset
PLLFEED_OFS     EQU     0x0C            ; PLL Feed Offset
PLLCON_PLLE     EQU     (1<<0)          ; PLL Enable
PLLCON_PLLC     EQU     (1<<1)          ; PLL Connect
PLLCFG_MSEL     EQU     (0x1F<<0)       ; PLL Multiplier
PLLCFG_PSEL     EQU     (0x03<<5)       ; PLL Divider
PLLSTAT_PLOCK   EQU     (1<<10)         ; PLL Lock Status
;// <e> PLL Setup
;//   <o1.0..4>   MSEL: PLL Multiplier Selection
;//               <1-32><#-1>
;//               <i> M Value
;//   <o1.5..6>   PSEL: PLL Divider Selection
;//               <0=> 1   <1=> 2   <2=> 4   <3=> 8
;//               <i> P Value
;// </e>
PLL_SETUP       EQU     1
PLLCFG_Val      EQU     0x00000024
```

That is defination of Registers for the generation of CPU frequency from the low frequency oscillator

```
; Setup PLL
            IF      PLL_SETUP <> 0
            LDR     R0, =PLL_BASE
            MOV     R1, #0xAA
            MOV     R2, #0x55

;  Configure and Enable PLL
            MOV     R3, #PLLCFG_Val
            STR     R3, [R0, #PLLCFG_OFS] 
            MOV     R3, #PLLCON_PLLE
            STR     R3, [R0, #PLLCON_OFS]
            STR     R1, [R0, #PLLFEED_OFS]
            STR     R2, [R0, #PLLFEED_OFS]


;  Wait until PLL Locked
PLL_Loop        LDR     R3, [R0, #PLLSTAT_OFS]
            ANDS    R3, R3, #PLLSTAT_PLOCK
            BEQ     PLL_Loop

;  Switch to PLL Clock
            MOV     R3, #(PLLCON_PLLE:OR:PLLCON_PLLC)
            STR     R3, [R0, #PLLCON_OFS]
            STR     R1, [R0, #PLLFEED_OFS]
            STR     R2, [R0, #PLLFEED_OFS]
            ENDIF   ; PLL_SETUP
```

This section of the startup.s File seems to be directly setting the clock to 60Mhz. Is what i understood from the startup.s file correct?

[LPC2148 User Manual](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiU_bOTkqTSAhXGK48KHSr7CrcQFggZMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nxp.com%2Fdocuments%2Fuser_manual%2FUM10139.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG5gDvnmdjp5V6KdNU-g0ceGBv66w&sig2=M2XW0fPeju70Vyy8i27Krw&bvm=bv.147448319,d.c2I)

Why is this startup.s file directly taking the CPU frequency to 60 Mhz?
If I need to change the CPU frequency should I do it in the Startup.s file or in the main section of my program ?

NOTE : I just switched from the AVR Microntrollers to ARM and I am more familiar with `#define F_CPU (Frequency of the XTAL)` hence the question.

Comment: "Why is this startup.s file directly taking the CPU frequency to 60 Mhz?" - it looks like it starts out at 1x XTAL frequency, so the startup is (somewhat arbitrarily) speeding it up for you. It may be relevant if you have any *derived* clocks, like a 48MHz USB clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still have this problem?

This can be set both in the `startup.s` file and in main code section.

It is up to you to decide which one to use.

In the startup.s file,

1. navigate to Configuration Wizard
2. Click PLL Setup
3. Set PLL Multiplier to `0x03`

In the main section of your program, you may obtain the code for setting the clock to 60Mhz from the LPC2119 docs.

Comment: The problem solved way back. But you pointed right so +1